# Get GPS position on a precise time interval

Tags: java, android, timer, gps, refresh

I'm trying to get gps postion as precise as posible at different interval ranges, i have few external gps,  10hz, 5hz and  1hz

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
car.this.getSystemService(car.this.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // Called when a new location is found

                }
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, 
locationListener);
```

With this way i get a log update like this  while driving at constant speed

```
10hz GPS

81ms  new position
79ms  new position
88ms  new position
96ms  new position
196ms new positon
60ms  new positon
256ms new position
70ms  new position

5 hz GPS

187ms new...
189ms ..
275ms ..
140ms ..
180ms ..
220ms ..
```

So i think onStatusChanged is initially faster than the nominal frequency but then saturates and causes bigs jumps

If i use a timer, it's works well and i get position each 100ms (200 or 1000) but the timer goes off around 100ms each 10 seconds

Edit: For clarify, i want to get a position each exact (or near) 100ms,200ms or 1000ms

****UPDATE 12-04-13

After redone my code to work with location.getTime() this are the results, all test were made at outside, at mid/hight speed and logging during 10 minutes for each device

```
HTC Sensation Z710e 4.0.3 Internal GPS 1HZ

Average Accuracy: 12.1m       
Average intertval: 1186ms
Min: 98ms
Max: 2621ms


HTC Desire HD 4.0.4 Internal GPS 1HZ

Average Accuracy: 10.6m        
Average intertval: 1211ms
Min: 144ms
Max: 2588ms


ASUS Transformer TF101 4.0.4 Internal GPS 1HZ

Average Accuracy: 18.15m       
Average intertval: 1000MS
Min: 1000ms
Max: 1000ms


SAMSUNG NOTE II GT-N7100 4.1.2 Internal GPS 1HZ (Glonass)

Average Accuracy: 6.8m          
Average intertval: 1000MS
Min: 1000ms
Max: 1001ms


SAMSUNG, HTC OR ASUS  with external GPS 5HZ

Average Accuracy: 2.2m  
Average intertval: 200MS
Min: 200ms
Max: 200ms


SAMSUNG, HTC OR ASUS  with external GPS 10HZ (Glonass)

Average Accuracy: 1.6m    
Average intertval: 100MS
Min: 100ms
Max: 100ms
```

Comment: The API affords you the ability to specify a minimum time, and minimum distance, that MUST elapse before you receive the next update. It does not however, afford you the ability to specify a time interval for reciving GPS updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont look at the (system) timestamp when you received the location, look at the timestamp of the location itself, if it is delivered by GPS it should be exactly 1000ms (1/hz).

Gps receivers never deliver odd milliseconds, they are exactly at millisecond 1000, when using 1hz.
use location.getTime(), and see yourself.

Comment: yeah! i was looking for currentTimeMillis() to know the elapsed time, that was the problem, too many thanks

Comment: i'm getting exact intervals (1s / hz) with external 5 & 10 hz gps but, with an internal 1hz gps sometimes i get 1s exact interval and sometimes i get beetween 0.6s and 1.3s , i not able to detect which makes the interval be unstable, accuracy maybe?

Comment: If it comes from GPS they should not vary, check outside, or restrict Location to GPS only. If you still get variation then the implementaion of GPS is bad done on (that) android phone.

Comment: I'm using LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER so is lock to gps only, i tried  outside, about 8 meters accuracy, i triend on both, HTC DESIRE HD and HTC SENSATION, both with crazy/random intervals

Comment: This sounds bad, I only heard of one case in my life, of such deviating time stamps. Try to check with other people, and post here your findings.

Comment: i update my question, htc's gps appear to be faulty/rubbish since the first day I bought it

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a precise time interval in a virtualized, multi-threaded application. You will get notifications when the OS gets around to running your thread, whether you use a timer or not.

Comment: Can you extend your comment?

Comment: Your OS is running a thread, and then it switches to running another thread. One of those threads is running code to check whether the clock has met a certain time interval. If that timer thread is running the entire time your application is running, then it will notify you the instant the time has elapsed. But that's not what happens. Instead, the OS runs the timer thread from time to time, and each time it runs, it checks the clock, and goes back to sleep. You have no way of forcing it to be running at the exact moment the time period has elapsed. Most likely another thread is running.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, you need to accept that you can only get so close to your ideal polling interval.

Comment: So what is the best/ accurate way to do an interval? btw great explanation